# Which template engine i have to use?

Tags: spring

i am developing website spring mvc , hibernate with my SQL database. my colleagues suggested to me to use free marker or velocity template engine but i'm using jsp template engine .i'm totally confused. So, can anyone please tell me jsp is best or not and why i will go for jsp or?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each one of them have some advantages that you could use if you need them, as always with this kind of questions the answers depends on what you want to achieve and how a template engine could help you.

For example, if you want to use the generated HTML pages as working mockups (because you need to show them), I would go for [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/). This [document](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thvsjsp.html) shows the key differences between Thymeleaf and JSP.

Comment: security is possible in jsp or not?

Comment: Yes, as long as you are using spring security you could use the tags: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html